# How to enable G729 audio codec in linphone 4.3.0 new SDK for android?

Tags: android, linphone, g729

Can you please help me out, How to enable G729 audio codec in linphone 4.3.0 SDK
please help me out for this as i am in trouble from a couple of days your help is great-full for me
hope some one help me...for this,,,thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Linphone 4.4.0 build steps as per below mention

Build dependencies Need to required setup in Linux
------------------------------------------------------------------
Common to all target platforms
The following tools must be installed on the build machine:

cmake >= 3.6
python = 2.7 (python 3.7 if C# wrapper generation is disabled)
pip
yasm
nasm
doxygen
Pystache (use pip install pystache)
six (use pip install six)

- Download the latest linphone-sdk
$ git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git -- recursive

- Successfully Android SDK download after below mention command execute
$ mkdir build
$ cd build

$ export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk && export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools && export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/ndk-bundle

$ cmake .. -DLINPHONESDK_PLATFORM:STRING=Android -DLINPHONESDK_ANDROID_ARCHS="arm64, armv7, x86_64, x86" -DENABLE_G729=YES -DENABLE_G729B_CNG=YES -DENABLE_VCARD=OFF -DENABLE_ILBC=OFF -DENABLE_SILK=OFF -DENABLE_ISAC=OFF -DENABLE_MKV=OFF -DENABLE_GSM=OFF -DENABLE_DOC=OFF -DENABLE_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_LIME=OFF -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=OFF -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=OFF

$ cmake --build .

- Successfully build generate after go to linphone-sdk/build/maven_repository/org/linphone/linphone-sdk-android/4.4.0-alpha.221+1d24dfa/linphone-sdk-android-4.4.0-alpha.221+1d24dfa.aar

- linphone-sdk-android-4.4.0-alpha.221+1d24dfa.aar this file import in android-studio and sync the project as per below mention steps

1)File -> New -> New Module -> Import .jar/.aar and import your .aar.

2)Then in your project’s build.gradle (the one under ‘app’) add the following:

dependencies {
compile project(':linphone-sdk-android-4.4.0-alpha.221+1d24dfa.aar')
}

3)Clean Build after all the above steps.
```

Comment: well done brother you saved my time its working fine thanks for sharing this valuable steps thank you so much dear